# PHPUnit Database testing with Mockery Framework

Tags: php, postgresql, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

recently I came across Mockery Framework for PHP mock object. I have a class which has constructor which takes postgreSQL connection parameters and connects to database and other methods for DML operations. I want to write test cases for these methods without actual connecting to database, hence want to use Mockery.

Below is a  simple example of DBConnection class. Could any one please give me a sample code for running test case for select method?

```
class DBConnection {
 private $conn; //db connection
 private $debug = false;
 private $schema;

 public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db, $schema = 'main', $debug = DEBUG) {
    $this->debug = $debug;
    $this->conn = pg_connect("host=$host user=$user password=$pass dbname=$db");
    if(!$this->conn) {
        throw new DatabaseException('Database connection failed');
         }
   }


  public function select() {
   $result = pg_prepare($this->conn, "my_query", 'SELECT * FROM shops WHERE name = $1');
   $result = pg_execute($this->conn, "my_query", array("Joe's Widgets"));
   return $result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to mock database ?

Comment: Is there any good alternative like test database or any other options available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to mock the `DBConnection->select()` method and ensure that the `pg_prepare()` and `pg_execute()` functions are called.

If the above is true, I wrote a composer package to help try to test php function calls `unit-testing/function-spy` (https://github.com/unit-testing/function-spy)

First, you'll have to namespace your `DBConnection` class. Let's assume it's in namespace `MyNamespace`. Then in your test, you can do something like this:

```
<?php namespace MyNamespace
    use UnitTesting\FunctionSpy\Spy;

    class DBConnectionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
        use \UnitTesting\FunctionSpy\SpyTrait;

        protected function setUp()
        {
            // init the spy
            $this->initSpy();
        }
        protected function tearDown()
        {
            // flush the spy so we can reset the calls after every test
            $this->flushSpy();
        }


        function test_construct_callsPgConnect_AndSetsConnection()
        {
             // create a fake return value for pg_connect()
             $this->spy['pg_connect'] = 'connection';
             $object = new DBConnection('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db', 'schema');
             $this->assertFunctionLastCalledWith('pg_connect', array('host=host user=user password=pass dbname=db'));

             $conn = $object->getConnection();  // your class doesn't have this method implemented, but it just returns the connection
             $this->assertEquals('connection', $conn);

        }

    }

    function pg_connect()
    { 
         return Spy::pg_connect();
    }
```